# Regular Expression in Apex to find entire link in string

Tags: apex, url, regular-expressions, string

I have a regular expression in apex that is only grabbing part of the link I need in a string. I need it to grab the entire link.

Here is what im working with:

```
String myvar = 'this is an example http://test.com/testing/123654123';

String myvar1 = '(?:(?:(?:[a-z0-9]{3,9}:(?://)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,w]+@)?[a-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+$??,w]+@)[a-z0-9.-]+)((?:/[+~%/.w-]*)?\\??(?:[-+=&;%@.w]*)#?w*)?)';

            Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(myvar1);

            Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(myvar);

            while (MyMatcher.find()) { 
                System.debug(MyMatcher.group());
                Location = MyMatcher.group();
        }
```

This is only returning http://test.com/

How can I modify the regular expression to provide the complete link?

Answer (score 1):

You might try a few of the regexps mentioned in the article [Detecting URLs in a Block of Text](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/) but the article also nails it by saying

> The short answer is that it can’t be done. Pretty much any character is valid in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

String myvar = 'this is an example http://test.com/testing/123654123';

String myvar1 = 'http'+myvar.split('http')[1];

System.debug(myvar1);

Comment: This doesn't work for me :(
I didn't provide the exact string in the example but it has alot of %'s around it Here is a better example of what myvar = looks like
String myvar = 'this is an example http://test.com/testing/123654123%0A%0A%0A%0A2.%20%20';

This is why I need to modify my regular expression

Comment: Any ideas? I really need to just modify im existing regex string